# Azure function with dynamic queue name output

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

Edit: rewriting question as I learned a lot more

Basically I want a function with a topic subscription trigger, that will then output to a queue, but the queue name is determined by the inbound message header. Pseudocode:

```
<-- @ServiceBusTopicTrigger(message)
outboundqueueName = getQueueName(message.getProperty('x'))
--> @ServiceBusQueueOutput(outboundQueueName)
```

So it seems I can create a function with topic trigger and configure an input from a cosmos DB for example and output to a queue.

But this will only work for a specific queue, how can I choose which queue to send to?

(Java coding)

TIA

Comment: please provide some code or more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't much else you need to do with the message except drop something on to dynamically determined queue, why not use a Logic App?

---

[image]

---

That screenshot's just a concept demo.  There's a great example of parsing JSON and selecting properties etc. documented here:

https://blogs.biztalk360.com/azure-logic-apps-event-hubs/